# Unable to order certificate using shell script in IBM secrets Manager

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-secrets-manager

I am getting the below message frequently while trying to execute the order public certificate api in shell script.

```
[{"error_message":"api auth request for subject: 'iam-ServiceId-bd8a0d74-82a0-48a3-9315-d940e149931d' action: 'secrets-manager.secret.create' resource 'crn:v1:bluemix:public:secrets-manager:us-south:a/585be4294d421d096580e222f89a3f55:c1576db9-7ceb-4001-a772-a1c5834c21a1:secret-group:a16d54c5-b484-2330-3d41-17085308f885' not permitted. trace: 'c5c03a25-b36f-4626-f21c-13593d0b5761'"}],"errors":[{"code":"secrets-manager.Error04091","message":"api auth request for subject: 'iam-ServiceId-bd8a0d74-82a0-48a3-9315-d940e149931d' action: 'secrets-manager.secret.create' resource 'crn:v1:bluemix:public:secrets-manager:us-south:a/585be4294d421d096580e222f89a3f55:c1576db9-7ceb-4001-a772-a1c5834c21a1:secret-group:a16d54c5-b484-2330-3d41-17085308f885' not permitted. trace: 'c5c03a25-b36f-4626-f21c-13593d0b5761'"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are either missing `Writer` service access policy on your User or Service ID, or the S2S configuration between Secrets Manager and your DNS provider is is misconfigured (eg `Manager` is required for CIS).